# How to move a specific result in a new colum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this problem getting the results of this query.

I need to output a new table called ManufacturingOrder2 with the following information:

The query is the next:

```
SELECT MP.workplace,
       MP.imputationDate,
       MP.shift,
       MO.ManufacturingReference,
       MS.ManufacturingOrder,
       SUM(MP.Duration) AS Microparos
FROM WorkplaceMicroStopStateHistory MP
     INNER JOIN ManufacturingStateHistory MS ON MS.company = MP.company
                                            AND MS.workplace = MP.workplace
                                            AND MS.imputationDate = MP.imputationDate
                                            AND MS.shift = MP.shift
     INNER JOIN ManufacturingOrder MO ON MO.company = MS.company
                                     AND MO.manufacturingOrder = MS.manufacturingOrder
WHERE MP.company = '0140'
  AND MP.shift = 'T1'
  AND MP.imputationDate > '20230227'
  AND MP.workplace = '07.12'
GROUP BY MP.company,
         MP.workplace,
         MP.shift,
         MP.imputationDate,
         MO.manufacturingReference,
         MS.manufacturingOrder;
```

And the result is this:

| workplace | Fecha | shift | ManufacturingReference | ManufacturingOrder | Microparos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07.12 | 2023-05-02 00:00:00.000 | T1 | 456925 | 624219-0450030 | 2663 |
| 07.12 | 2023-04-29 00:00:00.000 | T1 | 456925 | 623363-0450030 | 2499 |
| 07.12 | 2023-04-29 00:00:00.000 | T1 | 456925 | 624219-0450030 | 2499 |

What I need is this:

| workplace | Fecha | shift | ManufacturingReference | ManufacturingOrder | ManufacturingOrder2 | Microparos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07.12 | 2023-05-02 00:00:00.000 | T1 | 456925 | 624219-0450030 | NULL | 2663 |
| 07.12 | 2023-04-29 00:00:00.000 | T1 | 456925 | 623363-0450030 | 624219-0450030 | 2499 |

Comment: Not clear what's needed to achieve the desired output, can you edit your question and add more details

Comment: can you show example data?number of Manufacturing Order is dynamic or has two number?

Comment: Have you tried adding  `GROUP BY MP.Duration` at the end of the query?